# How do i add onclick function to my php code using html and echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

so i have this code i wrote and i want to add an onclick to the img, the problem is that when i add an onclick i need to use semi colons and the echo ends, how do i do that?

php:

```
echo '<div id="cloth"> <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" id="' . $row["Name"] . '"></div>';
```

what i want to add:

```
onclick="product('" . $row["name"] . "')"
```

i want it to look like that:

```
echo '<div id="cloth"> <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" id="' . $row["Name"] . '" onclick ="product("' . $row["Name"] . '")"></div>';
```

js product function:

```
function product(id) {
    var title = document.getElementById(id);
    sessionStorage.setItem("title", id);
    window.location.replace("product.php");
}
```

Comment: Put the semi-colons _inside_ the quotations. But, the code you say you want to add doesn't have a semi-colon in it.

Comment: Semi-colon would not end the echo if it's inside the string (as it needs to be)..you probably just made a typo. Show us your attempt to integrate that with the rest of your string.

Comment: @droopsnoot it needs to be a string and then it ruins everything

echo '<div id="cloth"> <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" id="' . $row["Name"] . '" onclick ="product("' . $row["Name"] . '")"></div>';

Comment: @ADyson

echo '<div id="cloth"> <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" id="' . $row["Name"] . '" onclick ="product("' . $row["Name"] . '")"></div>';

Comment: Add it to the question please - code does not belong in the comments, as you can see it's quite hard to read. Use the "edit" button underneath your question

Comment: P.S. Whilst this is certainly fixable, as a more modern alternative have you considered not using inline onclicks at all, and switching to unobtrusive event handling using addEventListener?

Comment: @ADyson how do i do that? and yes i will add this to my question

Comment: Anyway it looks like the issue has nothing to do with semicolons at all. Quote marks are your problem. Try `echo '<div id="cloth"> <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" id="' . $row["Name"] . '" onclick ="product(\"' . $row["Name"] . '\")"></div>';` so your're escaping the quote marks inside the onclick attribute properly

Comment: @ADyson doesnt work

Comment: means what? JS error, or something else? Be specific. "doesn't work" isn't a useful description of anything.

Comment: @ADyson sorry, when i click the image the function doesn't work

Comment: Try `echo '<div id="cloth"> <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" id="' . $row["Name"] . '" onclick ="product(\'' . $row["Name"] . '\')"></div>';
` instead

Comment: Again "doesn't work" isn't a useful description. Obviously it doesn't work otherwise you wouldn't be asking me about it. Learn to do basic debugging, and then you can say what actually happens. Do you understand that you can open your browser's Developer Tools and check for Javascript errors there in the Console?

Comment: i didnt know it, good to know, but the code you wrote me now works. thank you so much

Comment: Thanks. I will add as a proper answer below so you can mark it accepted, give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue has nothing to do with semicolons at all. Quote marks are your problem. Try

```
echo '<div id="cloth"> <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" id="' . $row["Name"] . '" onclick ="product(\'' . $row["Name"] . '\')"></div>';
```

so your're putting single quote marks inside the onclick attribute (to contrast with the double quotes which surround it) - then the browser isn't confused about which part is the attribute and which part is the hard-coded string inside it.

This will output something like

```
<div id="cloth"> <img src="lfkgjdfg" width="300" height="400" alt="dfggkk" style="margin: 15px;" id="dfggkk" onclick ="product('dfggkk')"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, stop using inline click attributes and instead use `addEventListener` to create unobtrusive event handlers which don't clutter up your HTML, and keep the code and markup separate - this usually makes for cleaner, more testable and more maintainable code.

To make this work, a couple of small adjustments are necessary to the markup so that the JS can identify the element, and also collect the correct name property from it when it's clicked.

Note: I'm assuming you're actually going to have several of these images in your page potentially, so I'm using a class to identify all the ones which should be clickable, and attaching event handlers to all of them:

PHP:

echo ' <img src="' . $row["Image_url"] . '" width="300" height="400" alt="' . $row["Name"] . '" style="margin: 15px;" class="clothImg" data-name="' . $row["Name"] . '">';
JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //wait until page is fully loaded
  let images = document.querySelectorAll(".clothImg"); //find images
  images.forEach(function(img) {
    img.addEventListener("click", function() { //add click handler
      product(this.dataset.name); //get name and pass to product function
    });
  });
});

function product(name) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("title", name);
    window.location.replace("product.php");
}
```

Live demo using sample output from the PHP:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //wait until page is fully loaded
  let images = document.querySelectorAll(".clothImg"); //find images
  images.forEach(function(img) {
    img.addEventListener("click", function() { //add click handler
      product(this.dataset.name); //get name and pass to product function
    });
  });
});

function product(name) {
    console.log(name); //just for demo
    //sessionStorage.setItem("title", name);
    //window.location.replace("product.php");
}
```

```html
<div id="cloth"> <img src="lfkgjdfg" width="300" height="400" alt="dfggkk" style="margin: 15px;" class="clothImg" data-name="dfggkk">
<img src="lblahvjhjkfg" width="300" height="400" alt="2222rd" style="margin: 15px;" class="clothImg" data-name="2222rd"></div>
```

Relevant documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

---

Along the same lines you could also stop using inline height, width and style properties, and use CSS rules instead which would apply to a whole class of elements.